# New SATA expansion card 'bootmgr is missing'

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, sata

I recently installed a new IO Crest 4 Port PCIe SATA III expansion card, because I was out of sata slots, and hooked up an older 100gig SSD I had as a third storage drive.

Installation went OK, I was able to quick format the new SSD, and I can use it.  However, now every time I boot up I get 'bootmgr is missing, press ctrl-alt-delete to reboot'. If I go into the bios before I get this message and exit without making any changes, the pc boots up fine.  I've removed the new ssd drive in the boot sequence in the bios also.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does your BIOS have any options about ensuring add-on cards are enabled all the time? does your expansion card have any configuration screen? E.g. some RAID cards have their own BIOS to configure RAID configurations.

Comment: What make and model motherboard do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot sequence in BIOS. Chage it to the drive on which the operating systrm is installed

Comment: The user has stated that they do not have to make any changes to the BIOS/boot order for the add-on card to allow the computer to boot. I.e. the user doesn't need to change boot order for the drive to be identified and booted from.